# How to change the -ss behavior from closest seek point before position to closest seek point after position

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any way to change the -ss behavior from closest seek point before position to closest seek point after position?

Example:

ffmpeg has the capability to select the seek point from **98** secs or **102** secs with in.mp4

If I use the following command, the ffmpeg will select the **98** secs as the seek point.

`ffmpeg -ss 100 -i in.mp4 -c copy out.mp4`

Is there any way to add some option but keep the `-ss 100` to make the ffmpeg to select the **102** as the seek point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used the shell script with `ffprobe` to achieve my goal.

Because of that `ffmpeg -ss T` will select the nearest keyframe before time **T**, so that I need to use `ffprobe` to get the next keyframe after time **T**.

The `ffprobe` reference command:

`ffprobe -skip_frame nokey -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv -read_intervals T+30`

The above command will show the keyframe timestamp from start to T+30.
So that I just need use some string processing with `bash` script to get the smallest timestamp which is greater than time **T**.
And don't forget to add 1 to next keyframe when use it as the `-ss` parameter with `ffmpeg`

My detailed `bash` script:

```
option="-skip_frame nokey -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv -read_intervals"
tg_file="test.mp4"
st_time=$1
probe_time=`expr $st_time + 20`
kf_arr=(`ffprobe ${option} %${probe_time} ${tg_file} | sed 's/.\+,//g'`)

for i in ${kf_arr[@]}
do
    if (( $(echo "$i > ${st_time}" | tr -d $'\r' | bc -l) )); then
        kf=${i%.*}
        st=`expr $kf + 1`
        break
    fi
done
```

`$1`: Expected start time

`tr -d $'\r'`: Remove the newline symbol in Windows system. (if you use the Linux you can ignore it)

`$st`: New timestamp (Next keyframe timestamp + 1 after expected start time)

If anyone has more convenient method to do that please kindly let me know, thanks!